# Prototype rewrite of jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

I'm a bit of a jQuery monkey and I've had a site dropped on me where I need to use a simple function to open links with rel="external" in a separate window.

In jQuery I do it like this:

```
// make links with rel=external open in new window/tab
$(function() {
    $('a[rel*=external]').click( function() {
        window.open(this.href);
        return false;
    });
});
```

How would I set up the same function in Prototype to be triggered unobtrusively on any links with rel=external attached to them?

Thanks

Simon

EDIT:

Following the advice of all three responses below the final code is:

```
    $(document).on('dom:loaded', function() {
    $$('a[rel*=external]').invoke('on','click', function(event) {
        window.open(this.href);
        event.stop();
    });
});
```

Thanks all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
    $$('a[rel*=external]').each(function(item) {
        $(item).observe('click', function(event) {
            window.open(this.href);
            event.stop();
        });
    });
});
```

And [here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XSs97/1/).

Comment: I would use "$(document).on('dom:loaded'" instead of "Event.observe(window, 'load'" and $(item).on instead of $(item).observe (it's the new 1.7 syntax)

Comment: @Stefaan, nice. I had forgotten the introduction of `on`. Also the `.each` can be reduced to `.invoke('on', 'click', function(event)...`